# Is it possible to set up Amazon's "Subscribe and Save" type feature for Craft Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, ecommerce

I'd like to allow customers to be able to automatically set up recurring purchases at a discounted price, much like Amazon's Subscribe and Save.

I had originally skimmed through the subscription portion of the documentation assuming this type of subscription would be supported, but soon realized that the current implementation is more meant for service-based subscriptions (for instance, it doesn't seem possible to add a subscription product to the cart).

I'm guessing at this point I will need to create a custom plugin to allow for a feature like this, but as a last resort decided to post my question here in case someone has needed something similar and had success.

Comment: did you get anywhere with this? As I am looking at something similar for a client.

Comment: I wasn't able to, unfortunately. Hope you have better luck than I did with it, @TerryUpton